# Redirect ip request (https or http) to domine (https)

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, https

This is my vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName mywebsite
            ServerAdmin mywebsite@mail.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www  

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]   

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName mywebsite
            ServerAdmin mywebsite@mail.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined   

    <Directory /var/www>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
     Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www
    Satisfy Any
    </Directory>


    #ssl protocol

    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    SSLCertificateFile cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile cert2
    SSLCertificateChainFile cert3


    </VirtualHost>
```

This condition redirect all http request to https.
for example
http://domine/wordpress to https://domine/wordpress
or
123.123.123.123/wordpress to https://123.123.123.123/wordpress

I need help for redirect an ip request to domine,
for example

123.123.123.123/wordpress to https://domine/wordpress
or
https://123.123.123.123/wordpress to https://domine/wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have only one domain name, the easiest is to redirect everything with one rule :

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes, 
i's my 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] `
and work for ip to https:/ip and domine to https:/domine , but not ip to domine
I do not want them to access the server through ip

Comment: just try my line and keep us informed

Comment: Good Work.  specifing mywebsite% also %{HTTP_HOST}%